# php mail form doesn't send email and results in 404 error

Tags: php, html

my php mail form works correctly in local host(it doesn't send anything of course, but no error is shown) . when I upload it however, clicking on submit button results in a 404 page being opened as a new tab. when I send it empty, there is no error. but if I put data in it I get error.
here is the code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
    {
        $num = $_REQUEST['num'] ;
        $desc = $_REQUEST['desc'];
        $subject = "einak";
        $nomr = $_REQUEST['nomr'] ;
        $sphr = $_REQUEST['sphr'] ;
        $cylr = $_REQUEST['cylr'] ;
        $angr = $_REQUEST['angr'] ;
        $addr = $_REQUEST['addr'] ;
        $diar = $_REQUEST['diar'] ;
        $noml = $_REQUEST['noml'] ;
        $sphl = $_REQUEST['sphl'] ;
        $cyll = $_REQUEST['cyll'] ;
        $angl = $_REQUEST['angl'] ;
        $addl = $_REQUEST['addl'] ;
        $dial = $_REQUEST['dial'] ;
        $type = $_REQUEST['type'] ; 
        $matter = $_REQUEST['matter'] ;
        $color = $_REQUEST['color'] ;
        $message = $num .  "<br />" . $nomr . "<br/>" . $sphr . "<br/>" . $cylr . "<br/>" . $angr . "<br />" . $addr . "<br />" . $diar . "<br />" . $noml . "<br/>" . $sphl . "<br/>" . $cyll . "<br/>" . $angl . "<br />" . $addl . "<br />" . $dial . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . "0" . "<br />" . $desc . "<br />"  . "<br />" . $type . "<br />" . $matter . "<br />" . $color . "<br />";
        $email = '';
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $email= '';
        mail ( "" , $email , $message , $headers ) ;
        echo "ارسال شما موفقیت آمیز بود";
    }
else
    {
      echo "<form method='post'>
                <input name='num' id='num' type='text' /> <br />
                <input type='text' name='nomr' id='nomr' > <br />
                <input type='text' name='sphr' id='sphr'> <br />
                <input type='text' name='cylr' id='cylr'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='angr' id='angr'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='addr' id='addr'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='diar' id='diar' > <br />
                <input type='text' name='noml' id='noml' > <br />
                <input type='text' name='sphl' id='sphl'> <br />
                <input type='text' name='cyll' id='cyll'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='angl' id='angl'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='addl' id='addl'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='dial' id='dial' > <br /> 
                <textarea id='desc' name='desc'> </textarea>          
                <input name='type' type='radio' value='bifocal' id='type1' />
                <input name='type' type='radio' value='progres' id='type2' />
                <input name='type' type='radio' value='single' id='type3' />
                <input name='type' type='radio' value='decen' id='type4' />
                <input name='matter' type='radio' value='glass' id='mat1' />
                <input name='matter' type='radio' value='plastic' id='mat2' />
                <input name='color' type='radio' value='single' id='col1' />
                <input name='color' type='radio' value='decen' id='col2' /> 
                <input type='submit' name='email' id='sb' value='ارسال اطلاعات' />
                <input type='text' name='name' id='name'  > <br />
                <input type='add' name='address' id='address'  > <br /> 
            </form >
            <p id='confirmation'></p>
            <input  type='submit'  id='vis' onClick='vis(); return false;'  value='تایید اطلاعات'/>";
    }
```

thanks
edit:if you want to see for yourselves here is the link http://toosoptic.ir/%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%85-%D8%B3%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B4-%D8%A2%D9%86%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86/

Answer (score 1):

Action page is missing ! you should supply the php page within action attribute.

```
<form action="yourpage.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Actually `$_REQUEST` can take `$_GET` or `$_POST`, its not a problem

Comment: An action attribute is not required. Without it (or with an empty action) the form will post to the current URL.

Comment: it seems this is NOT the problem . I tried different actions but it didn't work(I tried #, my website address etc.). I think the problem is something  else ?

Comment: @soheils did you check you server php.ini , and made sure sending mails is enabled ?!

Comment: Oh and using $_REQUEST _is_ a problem. You can't verify where the data comes from, it can be get, post or cookie. You should try to always use their respective arrays and never use request.

Comment: but I did send it with $_REQUEST before . now it doesn't work

Comment: @soheils have you tried using simple script to mail a simple string using your server ?

Comment: Huh? I do not know how to do that, but I have found out that the problem is related to the Name field

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to the `mail` command is the "to" address. You're leaving it empty. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: it was edited out to prevent abuse of my address, thanks to Mr. radical

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Sorry, missed that. I do notice you're using an email address as subject though. Could it be that your email is being sent, but just lands in spam filters? PHP mails tend to do that when sent without an extensive range of headers.

Comment: nope, I checked both the spam and inbox folders, even though I made sure the sending mail address is not spammed